# What kind of component would I need to put a break in a RS-485 bus?

Tags: transistors, relay, serial, solid-state-relay, rs485

I'd like to have some kind of electronically controlled switch (transistor, relay, solid-state relay, etc) that acts as a break in a RS-485 bus. The effect I would like is to optionally split the bus into two halves, isolating one half from the other. Obviously RS-485 signals would need to be transmitted clearly (even high-speed 2Mbps+ signals) when the switch is in the 'on' state and no signal should get through when the signal is in the 'off' state.

What kind of component should I be using, and how should I wire it up?

P.S. I'm looking for a component that is as physically small as possible, and I'd like the switching voltage to be 5V or lower.

P.P.S. The RS-485 bus cables in my application will be short enough that signal reflection won't be a problem, so I'm not going to worry about any termination at the moment. Nevertheless, bonus kudos is available for a solution that could optionally incorporate switching in a termination resistor on each side of the break - as I'm sure that would be useful to someone in the future.

Comment: You must have done some work on this so far - what have you uncovered that is not suitable in your eyes?

Comment: Are you planning for the switch to work on Master/slave or peer to peer or both? Is this for a DMX512 application?

Comment: This is not a DMX512 application - it would be high speed, 2Mbps or above, ideally.  This would be a master-slave bus, not a multiple master bus - but the slaves would still need to communicate back to the master upon the master's request. Hence only one of the isolated halves of the bus would be 'active' with any communication occurring only on the half that the master is on.

Comment: In terms of work I've done so far on this - not much: I don't know that much about this area - I'm not confident enough in my knowledge to know how to make a transistor to work as a switch in this case - and mechanical relays seem too large and there are possible problems with chatter caused by switch-on and switch-off. That, unfortunately, is as far as I got.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a relay, optionally switching over to a couple of termination resistors each side.

Edit following WRB's comment: If the system can't stand a bit of junk on the bus (which would seem like an oversight in something relying on RS485) then look at quiet relays (mercury wetted for example) or perhaps putting two RS485 transceiver IC's back to back.

Comment: No you can't. Contact bounce will cause horrendous bus errors.

Comment: I've seen people do worse in real systems (WORKING real systems). I've edited to add a bit more detail.

Comment: I could 'stand a bit of junk' on the bus, as you put it... I'd rather not have to, if at all possible. Also would like it if the components weren't too tall on the PCB (SMT components ideally)... I don't know of any relays that aren't quite tall - probably should save that for another question!

Comment: If you do it right, the contact bounce should not result in a legitimate differential transition, unless someone was talking at the time, in which case you would see corruption from the fragmented transmission no matter how clean your switch.

Comment: I'd also suggest that chopping the bus in half during data transmission is ALWAYS going to cause at least ONE error, so if your system can't handle that you're up the creek. Or you need to add intelligence to decide when to do the split.

Answer (score 1):

Placing a simple mechanical relay contact in line with an RS485 signal is asking for problems.  The contacts could chatter creating unknown noise on the line.  You also should not interrupt an RS485 line unless you are sure there is no data flowing in either direction.

A better method would be to use one or more analog multiplexer chips to route the signal pairs. If you have extra inputs or outputs you could put the termination resistors there and switch them in or out as needed. To prevent switching during a potential data stream you might try making the analog multiplexer system addressable by the master device.  Lots of sources for analog mux chips on the web. Just be sure to adhere to the signal level and through current limits of the selected chip.

Another possibility to keep things more compatible (to RS485 standards) would be to use an RS485 receiver chip and one or more driver chips, and in between them use a standard digital multiplexer.

Comment: The RS485 receiver/driver chip method was included because current levels on a 485 line can reach moderately high levels, for example on a system with several loaded down receiver ports.  In this case using an analog mux chip might cause significant voltage losses.

Comment: I like the idea of RS-485 receiver and then driver - this is pretty cheap, and requires little board space. I assume you could use a full-duplex / two-channel RS-485 chip for this purpose. I'm going to go and read up on analog and digital multiplexers before I mark this as the answer - but I think this is the best so far!

Comment: Some 485 chips are tiny and have in-built switchable termination. Joining two back-to-back with a basic circuit (maybe two logic gates) that can be switched on/off could make for a very low profile solution. Just watch the supported data rates through any given IC, not all are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "proper" half-duplex RS485, you can use a combination of an [LT1930](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1930f.pdf) to generate +/-15V rails from a 5V supply, and an [ADG5434](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADG5433_5434.pdf) to do the switching.  The +/-15V rails (well, at least +/-12V rails) are required because RS485 can have a common-mode voltage of up to +/-7V on the signalling pair, i.e. each trace can have between -7 and +12V at any given time.

I'm not going to draw the schematic for the LT1930 (refer pg 8 of the datasheet) but here's the schematic for the RS485 switching.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fodmSS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that all four switches in the ADG5434 must be switched simultaneously and in the same direction, and yes the buses are terminated.  You should be able to get it down to about 3sqcm of board space, 4 at the outside.

Now, issues.  It's going to be quite power-hungry (expect around 100mA at 5V for the LT1930 to generate the split supplies), and yes, it's not cheap.

On the upside, it has zero latency because it's switched.  No solution buffered through two UART's in an MCU has zero latency.

The problem with "just a switch" is that in this context you really have two choices for switches: electro-mechanical (a relay) or solid-state.  Relays have electrical isolation between the switching mechanism and the switched circuit, but they're large, consume quite a bit of switching current, and usually require more than 5V to operate.  Solid-state switches generally aren't isolated (there is an exception to this that I explain below) so they require a supply voltage that covers the possible voltage range of the signal being switched.

The exception is photo-coupled solid-state switches, like the [AQW612](http://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e_download/control/relay/photomos/catalog/semi_eng_ge1a1b_aqw61_e.pdf).  They are small, isolated and can switch high voltages (that one will switch 60V AC or DC from 1.14V or higher).  You could replace each switch in the above schematic with one AQW612 configured as a SPDT, and drive all of their inputs together.  Power consumption would be far lower, around 40mA when switched (and you'd have to change the termination resistors to 95 ohms), but the cost wouldn't exactly drop.

Comment: This seems like an excellent solution - thanks for the circuit diagram and the part numbers! The only thing I think is that it seems pretty expensive for 'just' a switch - total bill for parts for a microcontroller, RS-485 driver and the rest of the bits on the board is less than a quarter of what the LT1930+ADG5434 would cost. Surely this can be done for less money in a similar amount of board space?

Comment: I will up-vote when I have enough reputation!

Comment: Also what kind of power requirement would this have? It would be good if the final circuit would be as low-power as possible...

Answer (score 0):

A small DPDT relay will do you the mechanical part of separating the two halves of the buss, including adding termination resistors to both halves if necessary.

What you can't control is the amount of contact bounce.  This is not going to be a problem if the buss is idle - the termination resistors generally hold the buss in a specific idle state and separating the buss generally doesn't mess that up.

I'm quite partial to the Aromat telcom relays - DPDT in a DIP package with bifurcated gold contacts.  Very reliable and designed for long life.  Also not all that expensive.

You can get smaller relays but the price begins to increase accordingly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8EHXQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

PS - I wish that someone could tell me how to move the component text in the Circuit Lab schematic diagrams.